light-wrapper page-title
Good day Developers,
Please help. on my page it shows page title that I have no idea where to remove. I have checked my themes even changed them. Please if any one can tell me where I need to remove it? I do not understand coding, so if you can just tell me where to 'click' to remove it, that will help millions. I know how to inspect - so maybe you can guide me to the source of this annoyance..
Home
    
    



Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your wordpress using builder or not?
If ur site use elementor, edit/create new page with elementor => page settings 'gear icon' & check Hide Title


Source: https://elementor.com/help/how-to-hide-page-titles-in-wordpress/

Thank you so much for helping, but I am not using Elementor any more as I was also thinking it was that. I am now using Beaver and it still comes up.

Share your site here
